# Problem on improper integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm having some trouble evaluating the following integrals:
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^3}},\quad 
J=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^3}}.
$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, these are *improper* integrals, not indefinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $J$ integral is reduced to the [Euler integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) using $u$-substitution $u=x^3$:
$$
  J = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \left(1-u\right)^{1/2-1} u^{1/3-1} \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{3} \operatorname{Beta}\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2} \right) 
$$
The $I$ integral can be reduced to the beta integral using $x^3 = \frac{u}{1-u}$, i.e. $u=\frac{x^3}{1+x^3}$:
$$
  I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} =\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 u^{1/3-1} \left(1-u\right)^{1/6-1} \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{3} \operatorname{Beta}\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{6} \right) 
$$

Comment: Why do you get $(1-u)^{-5/6}$ in the $I$ integral? When I do the substitution, I find:
$$\sqrt{1+x^3}=\sqrt{1+\frac{u}{1-u}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-u}}=(1-u)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: Are you forgetting the Jacobian?

Comment: I think so, can you please elaborate.

Comment: $x = u^{1/3} (1-u)^{1/3}$. The Jacobian is just $dx/du$, but it is far easier to derive it from $\frac{d x^3}{d u}=d\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\rught)$, and then substitute the calue of x^2.